# .Net Remoting security

Tags: .net, security, remoting

I have a .Net Library running as windows service and it is called using .Net Remoting with TCP connection.
Is there a way to limit the applications that can call this service, i. e., can I specify that only Applications aa.exe and bb.exe are allowed to call this service and reject calls from other applications?

Answer (score 1):

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59hafwyt(v=vs.85).aspx) describes how to use authentication with a remoting TCP channel.

You can authenticate by identity, or by IP address, but you won't know which application is running on the client.

In order to restrict access to specific applications, you would need to provide a custom mechanism for these applications to be able to present credentials to the remoting service, and you would need to take steps to ensure these credentials couldn't be used by other applications.

But this is not really feasible: you could, for example, embed such credentials in the relevant executables aa.exe and bb.exe, and possibly obfuscate them to make them harder to discover, but a determined attacker would be able to obtain them and use them from a different application.